# Could someone help me understand what this is asking

Tags: java, google-chrome, logic

To help Beta Rabbit crack the lock, write a function answer(n) which returns the smallest positive integer base b, at least 2, in which the integer n is a palindrome. The input n will satisfy "0 <= n <= 1000."

## Test cases

Inputs:
    (int) n = 0
Output:
    (int) 2

Inputs:
    (int) n = 42
Output:
    (int) 4

it is not the problem I need help with as there are similar ones on this site. It is the actual question. this input n they talk about, what the hell does it stand for? It can't be the base as b represents the base. It is not the positive integer they want for output because it is independent of that number and in the test cases it doesn't seem to have any correlation with it. Does it just want me to find the smallest palindrome of any base that's less than 1000 in decimal? Thanks to anyone that takes the time to help me figure this out , it's part of Google's foobar questions. I don't mind doing the work to solve the flecking thing as long as I can understand what the thing is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is Google Foobar?
2. I may not give you a full answer, but think about it this way. The number n, convert it to the output base... see if it's a palindrome

Comment: What do you mean by convert it to the output base? As for foobar wait's these set of coding challenges from google, you can find them at http://146.148.62.204 the first part I will give you a hint because it's really unclear, interpret the regex by itself, it does not go with any string, the answer is within the regex.

Comment: The output is the base you need to convert the number to.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks I got this now.